# How do I configure Linux to log when ulimits are hit?

Tags: linux, centos, logging, ulimit

For example, say I'm hitting nproc. I would expect a log message to appear /var/log/messages or similar, but it looks like that needs to be configured. How do I do that? I can't find anything relevant on google so far. OS is CentOS 6.4. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't finding anything because it doesn't exist.  It is up to the application hitting the limit to log that a syscall failed to allocate a resource.

Some quick googlefu led me to the [Logging-limits.conf](https://github.com/PaulDaviesC/Logging-limits.conf) on github.  It attempts to log when the syscalls fail with auditd.  I have no experience with this package, it may destroy your system.  Caveat emptor.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help! I'll take a look at that project.